# Odd textInput data-binding for ko-js and jquery mobile

Tags: json, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am seeing a very weird issue. I am using ko-js to data-bind some form-fields in a jQuery mobile app. I am successfully binding all the other fields using selects and flipswitches, but the input type="text elements are not binding inputText on the required field in my viewmodel. If I bind to another field in the viewmodel it gets correctly displayed/updated.

So if bind with

```
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: controlData, attr:{'id': ftId()}" >
```

I get no value in the input, but if I bind with

```
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: label, attr:{'id': ftId()}" >
```

it works perfectly

fuller HTML excerpt:

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
  <div id="container">
    <div data-bind="foreach: formFields">
      <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-bind="visible: isFieldText()">
        <label data-bind="for: ftId(), text: label()"></label>
        <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: controlData, attr:{'id': ftId()}" >                                          
      </div>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-bind="visible: isFieldCheckbox()">
        <label data-bind="for: cbId(), text: label()"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" data-bind="attr: {'id': cbId(), 'data-on-text': dataOnText(), 'data-off-text': dataOffText()}, checked:controlData" /> <!--data-wrapper-class="custom-size-flipswitch"-->        
      </div>            
      <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-bind="visible: isFieldSelect()">
        <label data-bind="for: selectId(), text: label()"></label>
        <select data-bind="attr: {'id': selectId()}, options: options, value: controlData"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Viewmodel and applyBindings code

```
var formFieldViewModel = function (data, target, parent) {
var _this = this;
this.isFieldText = ko.computed(function() {
return _this.controlType() === "text" ? true : false;
});
this.isFieldCheckbox = ko.computed(function() {
return _this.controlType() === "checkbox" ? true : false;
});
this.isFieldSelect = ko.computed(function() {
return _this.controlType() === "select" ? true : false;
});
this.ftId = ko.computed(function() {
return 'ft_'+_this.index();
});
this.cbId = ko.computed(function() {
return 'cb_'+_this.index();
});
this.selectId = ko.computed(function() {
return 'select_'+_this.index();
});
//-- Call mapping function --//
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, target, this);
};
```

Here's the JSON object - the JSON validates at JSONlint

```
{"formFields":[{"index":0,"label":"experiment description","controlData":"dummy","controlType":"text","dataOffText":"","dataOnText":"","options":[]},{"index":1,"label":"odd S1 Label","controlData":"scottish","controlType":"text","dataOffText":"","dataOnText":"","options":[]},{"index":2,"label":"even S1 Label","controlData":"english","controlType":"text","dataOffText":"","dataOnText":"","options":[]},{"index":3,"label":"use 3P classic","controlData":false,"controlType":"checkbox","dataOffText":"no","dataOnText":"yes","options":[]},{"index":4,"label":"subject","controlData":"National identity","controlType":"select","dataOffText":"","dataOnText":"","options":["Sexuality","Religion","Race \u0026 Culture","National identity","Immigrant culture - football","Gender"]},{"index":5,"label":"country","controlData":"United Kingdom","controlType":"select","dataOffText":"","dataOnText":"","options":["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","American Samoa","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antarctica","Antigua and Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia and Herzegovina","Botswana","Bouvet Island","Brazil","British Indian Ocean Territory","Brunei Darussalam","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central African Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Christmas Island","Cocos (Keeling) Islands","Colombia","Comoros","Congo","Congo, the Democratic Republic of the","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D\u0027Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands (Malvinas)","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Guiana","French Polynesia","French Southern Territories","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guadeloupe","Guam","Guatemala","Guinea","Guinea-Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands","Holy See (Vatican City State)","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran, Islamic Republic of","Iraq","Ireland","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Korea, Democratic People\u0027s Republic of","Korea, Republic of","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Lao People\u0027s Democratic Republic","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libyan Arab Jamahiriya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macao","Macedonia, the Former Yugoslav Republic of","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Martinique","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mayotte","Mexico","Micronesia, Federated States of","Moldova, Republic of","Monaco","Mongolia","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauru","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","Niue","Norfolk Island","Northern Mariana Islands","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palau","Palestinian Territory, Occupied","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Pitcairn","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russian Federation","Rwanda","Saint Helena","Saint Kitts and Nevis","Saint Lucia","Saint Pierre and Miquelon","Saint Vincent and the Grenadines","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia and Montenegro","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands","Spain","Sri Lanka","Sudan","Suriname","Svalbard and Jan Mayen","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syrian Arab Republic","Taiwan, Province of China","Tajikistan","Tanzania, United Republic of","Thailand","Timor-Leste","Togo","Tokelau","Tonga","Trinidad and Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks and Caicos Islands","Tuvalu","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States","United States Minor Outlying Islands","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Vanuatu","Venezuela","Viet Nam","Virgin Islands, British","Virgin Islands, U.s.","Wallis and Futuna","Western Sahara","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"]},{"index":6,"label":"language","controlData":"English","controlType":"select","dataOffText":"","dataOnText":"","options":["Afrikaans","Albanian","Arabic","Armenian","Basque","Bengali","Bulgarian","Catalan","Cambodian","Chinese (Mandarin)","Croation","Czech","Danish","Dutch","English","Estonian","Fiji","Finnish","French","Georgian","German","Greek","Gujarati","Hebrew","Hindi","Hungarian","Icelandic","Indonesian","Irish","Italian","Japanese","Javanese","Korean","Latin","Latvian","Lithuanian","Macedonian","Malay","Malayalam","Maltese","Maori","Marathi","Mongolian","Nepali","Norwegian","Persian","Polish","Portuguese","Punjabi","Quechua","Romanian","Russian","Samoan","Serbian","Slovak","Slovenian","Spanish","Swahili","Swedish","Tamil","Tatar","Telugu","Thai","Tibetan","Tonga","Turkish","Ukranian","Urdu","Uzbek","Vietnamese","Welsh","Xhosa"]},{"index":7,"label":"location","controlData":"Southampton","controlType":"select","dataOffText":"","dataOnText":"","options":["Cardiff","Bournemouth","Upsalla","Rotterdam","Madrid","Southampton","Trondheim","Port Elizabeth","Cape Town","Helsinki","Pisa","Wroclaw","Palermo","Budapest","Malaga","Magaluth","Caerdydd","Glamorgan","Granada","Geneva","Berlin"]}]}
```

Comment: I'm commenting on my own question. I've solved the issue by extending my JSON object so that I have a "itemValue" and a "selectedItem" injected into the viewmodel, even though the content for these is the same. I've changed the html binding so that the input element binds textInput to "itemValue" and the select/checkbox items bind value to "selectedItem". I can only think that the 2 way bindings incurred by having different element types binding to the same value in the viewmodel are interacting with each other. Thanks to anyone who has made the effort to read all this.

Comment: Another option is to use [`if` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html), since your blocks are mutually exclusive. This way knockout won't bother binding not applicable blocks (as with `visible` binding) and your code should work.

Comment: Ilya's suggestion is spot on. Although my approach works, Ilya's approach is cleaner as the logic is clearer from the binding statement rather than have to understand the extra fields in my JSON object